# Wordpress: wp_query doesn't work well when post_type and category_name both arguments are passed

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Test 1:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'page',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

print_r($query);
```

The result:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [posts_per_page] => 10
            [post_type] => page
        )

    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [posts_per_page] => 10
            [post_type] => page
```

Test 2:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'category_name' =>'latest-updates-home-page'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

print_r($query);
```

Result:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [posts_per_page] => 10
            [post_type] => page
            [category_name] => latest-updates-home-page
        )

    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [posts_per_page] => 10
            [post_type] => any
            [category_name] => latest-updates-home-page
```

As it can be seen that 'post_type' under 'query_vars' array changes to 'any' when category_name and post_type both are passed as argument.

Is there any way I can loop up for a particular post_type with a particular category_name?

Comment: Are you really creating page category?

Comment: I wanna use it for sliding banner where it will show all products + pages under a particular category.